# Date Range using frequency and periods

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, date-range

I built a routine that creates me a list of dates using different frequencies and also periods, the only thing I cannot get working is using the periods while using 'M' for end of the month entries.

```
def run_date_creator(start_date, end_date, steps, interval):
    #Interval: Days(d or D), Weeks (w or W), Month (m or M), Quarters (q or Q) and Years(y or Y) 
    start_date = pd.to_datetime(start_date) 
    end_date   = pd.to_datetime(end_date)
    if interval == 'd' or interval == 'D':
        dates = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq=pd.tseries.offsets.DateOffset(days=1*steps))
    elif interval == 'w':
        dates = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq=pd.tseries.offsets.DateOffset(days=7*steps))
    elif interval == 'bm' or interval == 'BM':
        dates = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq=pd.tseries.offsets.DateOffset(months=1*steps))
    elif interval == 'em' or interval == 'EM':
        dates = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq='M')
    elif interval == 'q' or interval == 'Q':
        dates = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq=pd.tseries.offsets.DateOffset(months=3*steps))
    elif interval == 'y' or interval == 'Y':
        dates = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq=pd.tseries.offsets.DateOffset(months=12*steps))
    return list(dates.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))

start_date = '2017-1-1'
end_date  = '2017-12-31'

dates = run_date_creator(start_date, end_date , 2, 'em')
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: this works for me: `pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq='M')` gives `DatetimeIndex(['2017-01-31', '2017-02-28', '2017-03-31', '2017-04-30',
               '2017-05-31', '2017-06-30', '2017-07-31', '2017-08-31',
               '2017-09-30', '2017-10-31', '2017-11-30', '2017-12-31'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='M')`

Comment: sorry typo, it was meant to use steps = 2 to get you  '2017-01-31',  '2017-03-31', '2017-05-31', etc

Comment: Couple of things: 1) you say your problem is only with 'M', but I don't see you using 'M'. Do you mean 'EM'? 2) if that's really your only problem, you should isolate your example to include only that. 3) Consider using a dictionary instead of all those `if/elif`statements. 4) Use e.g., `interval.lower() == 'd'` instead of checking for upper and lower case intervals (handles the case where you get `'Em'`)

Comment: @Markus.london what does that mean? Typo in the question? Typo caused the problem?

Comment: Still don't understand the problem and your comment doesn't match your question as only 'mb' or 'MB' uses the step arg, besides I get this: `pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq=pd.tseries.offsets.DateOffset(months=1*2))
Out[63]:
DatetimeIndex(['2017-01-01', '2017-03-01', '2017-05-01', '2017-07-01',
               '2017-09-01', '2017-11-01'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='<DateOffset: kwds={'months': 2}>')`

Comment: typo in the question, I edited it. I am using 'em' in my function call, in the corresponding elif section it uses freq = 'M' , em should stand for end of month

Comment: I refer you to my first comment for which it shows that it works, your branch doesn't use any step arg so again your question is unclear to me (and probably others). You've not edited your question to show what the desired output should be, additionally you should post only the relevant code that fails, if the rest of the branches work then remove them to just the line of code that you state fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify steps in `freq`.

```
dates = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq='%dM' % steps)
```